# Can you run Windows executables built on the .NET framework on a Mac?

Tags: windows, macos, .net-framework, mono-framework, .net-core

I understand the Microsoft has ditched the [.NET Framework](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-framework) in favour of the cross platform [.NET Core](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download). I have a Windows .exe file build using the .NET Framework. Can I use the new .NET Core to execute it on macOS? Or is [Mono](https://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/supported-platforms/macos/) the better solution?

Answer (score 0):

For reasons entirely unrelated to .NET; You cannot normally run any executable built for Windows on a Mac. One major problem can be a difference in CPU architecture, but even if both systems are the same architecture the executable binaries just aren't set up to run the same way on both OS's.

If the executable was built for windows with an x86 CPU then it may still be possible to run it on a Mac with an x86 CPU using [Wine](https://www.winehq.org/). (*Considering that Apple is releasing Macs with ARM cpus now this may not be a solution for much longer*..)
Wine is able to open the executable, and if it is a .NET Framework application it will be looking for the .NET Framework runtime it was built for. Wine uses Mono to substitute that .NET Framework runtime, since Mono is built to be a drop-in replacement for .NET Framework that runs on more platforms than just Windows.

.NET Core is an entirely different runtime from .NET Framework and will not run applications that are already built for .NET Framework.

.NET Core *can* support applications originally written for .NET Framework by rebuilding the application from source so that it targets .NET Core. It will usually need some changes to account for the different APIs of the two runtimes.

Comment: In a short: you can *either* use Wine or try running with .NET Core runtime installed ?

Comment: No, .NET Core is not the same thing as .NET Framework. Not even worth trying .NET Core if the application was built to depend on .NET Framework. You need **both** mono and wine, not either/or.